# how to add headers to network request in swift

Tags: swift

How can I add custom headers to this APIService. Basically I am trying to add headersDict to the headers of the api network call. but not sure how to add them

when I print headersDict to console it looks like this

```
["x-request-id": "d8099384-0720-425d-bfe2-f9cef572f443", "host": "RJB-production.up.railway.app", "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", "postman-token": "85b08d4f-d914-4e0c-a74e-67537fe01dc3", "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.29.2", "x-forwarded-proto": "https", "x-forwarded-for": "75.178.112.100", "e-devicename": "postman", "x-envoy-external-address": "75.178.112.100", "e-uuid": "e8edec14-ce38-42b5-93b0-3fee05fca1eb", "room-id": "123room", "e-clienticon": "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/1024.png", "accept": "*/*", "e-clientname": "postman"]
```

My APIService.swift looks like this

```
import Foundation
class APIService {
     let urlString: String
     let headersDict: [String: String]  // Custom headers
     init(urlString: String, headersDict: [String: String]) {
        self.urlString = urlString
        self.headersDict = headersDict
    }
    
    func getJSON<T: Decodable>(dateDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy = .deferredToDate,
                               keyDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy = .useDefaultKeys) async throws -> T {
        guard
            let url = URL(string: urlString)
        else {
            throw APIError.invalidURL
        }
        
        // Set custom headers if available
        headersDict.forEach { key, value in
            urlRequest.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }
        
        do {
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            guard
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                httpResponse.statusCode == 200
            else {
                throw APIError.invalidResponseStatus
            }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = dateDecodingStrategy
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = keyDecodingStrategy
            do {
                let decodedData = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
                return decodedData
            } catch {
                throw APIError.decodingError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch {
            throw APIError.dataTaskError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

enum APIError: Error, LocalizedError {
    case invalidURL
    case invalidResponseStatus
    case dataTaskError(String)
    case corruptData
    case decodingError(String)
    
    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .invalidURL:
            return NSLocalizedString("The endpoint URL is invalid", comment: "")
        case .invalidResponseStatus:
            return NSLocalizedString("The APIO failed to issue a valid response.", comment: "")
        case .dataTaskError(let string):
            return string
        case .corruptData:
            return NSLocalizedString("The data provided appears to be corrupt", comment: "")
        case .decodingError(let string):
            return string
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I am trying to append these headers to the network request. When I call the class I am passing the url and the headers. The headers are being passed as a dictionary. I just don't know how to add them to the network request

Comment: Make a URLRequest.

Comment: @matt IMHO, the answers in the links are not the optimal. These answers - as well as the OPs original question –  take a _dictionary_ representing the custom headers and use URLRequest's `setValue(_: forHTTPHeaderField:)`. What suits the header semantic of URL request better, would be to use an array of tuples (aka `[(String, String)]`) defining the custom headers and then use URLRequest's `addValue(_:forHTTPHeaderField:)` to configure the request.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper The point is that the OP is not using a URLRequest at all.  The networking call is `URLSession.shared.data(from: url)`.